# Extract function from terra in R only returns empty results

Tags: r, gis, raster, shapefile, terra

I am trying to use the `extract()` function from `terra` in R, but I am probably doing something wrong, since I am only getting empty/null results.

Basically, I have a SpatRaster with several values describing the land use of 30 x 30 m grid cells (for example, 1 could be forest, 2 corn, 3 soybeans, etc...). I want to extract these values using a SpatVector with several polygons (original shapefile available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1negLgW_-xP6tfAKSrbg1A_3fhsxFYr4w/view?usp=share_link)). I do not want to extract the values from the SpatRaster using the values directly, but I want to first create a buffer around the polygons in my SpatVector using `terra::buffer()` and then extract the values. My polygons (and buffers) are larger than the gridcells in the SpatRaster. Hence, I am hoping to get the values for all the grid cells that fall within the polygons. Since the buffers/polygons may have different sizes, some of these polygons would have longer lists of values extracted than others.

Below I provide a reproducible example (using the shapefile linked above) and describe what I have tried.

Get the SpatRaster data. To download it on Linux using the R package `CropscapeR` I need to do the process below (in Windows it is easier):

```
library(CropScapeR)
library(terra)
# Skip the SSL check
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
# Automatically generate a temporary path to save the data
tif_file <- tempfile(fileext = '.tif')
# Download the raster TIF file into specified path, also read into R
# This is a county in Minnesota, US
ST_CDL <- GetCDLData(aoi = '27001', year = 2020, type = 'f', save_path = tif_file) 
terra::writeRaster(ST_CDL, "ST_CDL.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
ST_CDL = terra::rast("ST_CDL.tif")
```

Get the Spatvector data and create the buffers:

```
CLU_MN <- vect("~/clu_public_a_mn001.shp")
# unique(is.valid(CLU_MN)) -> the SpatVector is valid
# Creating 1km buffers
CLU_MN_buffer <- terra::buffer(CLU_MN, 1000)
# Projecting CLU_MN_buffer to the same projection as the SpatRaster
CLU_MN_buffer <- terra::project(CLU_MN_buffer, crs(ST_CDL))
```

Extract the values of `ST_CDL` using `CLU_MN_buffer` (I have tried a few different things here):

```
# Returns NAs in the second column
try1 <- terra::extract(ST_CDL, CLU_MN_buffer)
# Returns a dataframe with 0 observations
try2 <- terra::extract(ST_CDL, CLU_MN_buffer, weights=TRUE)
# Returns an error message, although the syntax should be fine from what is written in the error message:
# Error: [extract] if 'weights' or 'exact' is TRUE, you can only use functions mean, sum, min, max and table
try3 <- terra::extract(ST_CDL, CLU_MN_buffer, fun=table, weights=TRUE)
# Returns tables of extent 0
try4 <- terra::extract(ST_CDL, CLU_MN_buffer, fun=table)
```

I am unsure if I am missing specifying something, but any help will be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide `clu_public_a_mn001.shp` file so that we can run your code?

Comment: @UseR10085, it is actually provided in third line of the second paragraph. Just in case I am providing it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1negLgW_-xP6tfAKSrbg1A_3fhsxFYr4w/view?usp=share_link) again.